# Can someone help me to convert this Python to VBscript for labellling

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, vbscript, maplex

I have two Python script snippets that need to convert to VBscript.

Can anybody help me because I am really not familiar and know Python.

the first script is

```
def FindLabel([BA2]):
    name = str([BA2])
    if "-" in name:
        first, second = name.split("-",1)
        for letter in first:
            if not letter.isalnum():
                first = first.strip(letter)
        return first
    else:
    return name
```

the second script is:

```
def FindLabel([BA2]):
    name = str([BA2])
    if "-" in name:
        first, second = name.split("-",1)
        for letter in second:
            if not letter.isalnum():
                second = second.strip(letter)
        return second   
    else:
        return name
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert them?  Since 10.1 there has been a Python parser for Label Expressions and you appear to be using 10.2.

Comment: Note that you should avoid using [] is the name of a variable.

Comment: the reason why i want to use the vb script, i want to standardize it since other expression i used vbscript..

Comment: Standardizing on Python would make more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy, the functions in VBScript are limited. I think you would be better standardizing to python as it offers **far more** functions and options than VBScript which is on the way out. However, in the interest of just answering the question...

As I understand it you want to take the first word if there is a dash but only display the alphanumeric characters and if there is no dash then just the contents of BA2.

```
Function FindLabel ([BA2])
     if InStr([BA2],"-") > 0 then
       BA_Split = split([BA2],"-")
       ThisWord = BA_Split(0)
       OutString = ""
       for index = 1 to len(ThisWord) 
         SingleLetter = mid(ThisWord,index,1)
         if asc(SingleLetter) >= 48 and asc(SingleLetter) <= 57 then
           OutString = OutString & SingleLetter
         elseif asc(SingleLetter) >= 65 and asc(SingleLetter) <= 90 then
           OutString = OutString & SingleLetter
         elseif asc(SingleLetter) >= 97 and asc(SingleLetter) <= 122 then
           OutString = OutString & SingleLetter
         end if
       next
       FindLabel = OutString
     else
       FindLabel = [BA2]
     end if
End Function
```

There is no `isalnum()` in VBScript, so instead I use the ASCII ranges for 0 to 9, A to Z and a to z... if in this range then append to `OutString`

The second function is the same as the first except you use the second word:

```
Function FindLabel ([BA2])
     if InStr([BA2],"-") > 0 then
       BA_Split = split([BA2],"-")
       ThisWord = BA_Split(1)
       OutString = ""
       for index = 1 to len(ThisWord) 
         SingleLetter = mid(ThisWord,index,1)
         if asc(SingleLetter) >= 48 and asc(SingleLetter) <= 57 then
           OutString = OutString & SingleLetter
         elseif asc(SingleLetter) >= 65 and asc(SingleLetter) <= 90 then
           OutString = OutString & SingleLetter
         elseif asc(SingleLetter) >= 97 and asc(SingleLetter) <= 122 then
           OutString = OutString & SingleLetter
         end if
       next
       FindLabel = OutString
     else
       FindLabel = [BA2]
     end if
End Function
```

Comment: yup,,phyton far more function but im really not familiar with that..thank you so much for helping me..its really help me to solve my problem..thank you once again..

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend looking into python, it reads almost as well as VBSCript but can do much more. I don't like the editor interface with the label scripts so I write in another editor and copy in.